# Is there way to create a sync between MongoDb atlas and mongodb compass using node or python?

Tags: python, node.js, mongodb

I want run a code for downloading db from MongoDb Atlas and the uploading it on MongoDb Compass all using node or python

I have tried MongoDB tools but I was looking for an easier way to do it preferably in node or python

Comment: How could be be even easier than using `mongoexport` or `mongodump`?